# Acquiring frames in real time using kinect v2 in python

Tags: python, opencv, kinect-v2, pykinect

How can I get frames of skeletal data in real time using kinect v2 in python?

How do I acquire an mp4 video file using kinect v2?

The file format of video which is acquired using kinect studio is .xef, but how do I separate frames of this .xef file using python?

Comment: Tidied up English

Answer (score 0):

Check this out
https://github.com/Kinect/PyKinect2
This is a wrapper in Python for Kinect v2 SDK.